Using capacitive/inductive proximity sensors to detect aluminium soda cans
A project taking part in my robotics club involves making a smart trashcan for sorting glass, plastics, metal (non ferrous and ferrous) and paper based trash. aluminium soda cans are quite thin (0.11mm) and while the detector+can will be in close proximity, it might not be enough to close the switch. Inductive sensors are not as sensitive with non ferrous metals of this thickness, so is a capacitive sensor a better alternative? Can it detect aluminium at this thickness?

have you tried an inductive sensor on a can yet, or are you just nervous? It depends somewhat on its operating frequency.

@Neil_UK I spent 2 hours yesterday arguing with my mentor on this theme. He gave me a datasheet for an Omron compact sensor and told me that the sensitivity for aluminium starts at some minimum of 1mm thickness. We are going to test them out on a real circuit, but I want other opinions and alternatives to try out and present to him as we are pressed by a deadline. I don't understand the downvote on this question?

Checking capacity, how would an Al can show up any differently from aluminized plastic, e.g., cellophane chips wrapper? Investigate how Al objects slow when dropped in a magnetic field due to eddy currents. You'd need to use a way to turn off the magnetic field to keep ferrous objects from sticking, too. See this coin sorter for uinspiration: https://web.mit.edu/2.972/www/reports/coin_tester/coin_tester.htm
